# Setting Page.IsValid to False

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, jquery-ui, datepicker

I've got an ASP user control which is basically using jquery UI datepicker just we'd have a standard calendar throughout our site.

I am trying to create a validation for this control so I would not have to create the validation in every page using the calendar. Is it possible to set the Page_IsValid to false from the ascx?

Here's the code:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="jQueryCalendar.ascx.vb" Inherits="Controls_Misc_jQueryCalendar" %>

    <style type="text/css">
        div.ui-datepicker, div.ui-widget {
            font-size: 12px !important;
        }
        img.ui-datepicker-trigger{
            margin-bottom:-5px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImage: '<%= Me.ImageURL%>',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            });
        });            
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IsValid` property is read-only and therefore cannot be set. Add a validator-control to your user control!

I see your user control does not contain the text-input for the datepicker at the moment, but instead adds the datepicker to all items of the class `datepicker`. I suggest you change this so you have the `TextBox` inside the usercontrol, this way you can put a validator control on it.

Comment: I have a textbox, didn't realise that I didn't include it in the question, my apologies there.

I don't know how I didn't think about putting a validator inside the control itself, thanks.